# Azure B2C Single Sign On (SSO) not working as expected

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am working on Azure B2c sometime now. I am trying to implement single sign on on (SSO) multiple application. I am also sharing same login profile on multiple application but its not working.

I created tenant with multiple application. Individual application can login with expected claim information. But I am expecting to login one application should automatically login other application. At this moment every application asking login the system.  According to Microsoft documentation, session behaviour should be shared between application.

here is my login profile

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
    client_id=3ef6aa38-2d21-4ee9-9bf8-8bceb5cfe64b
    &redirect_uri=https://localhost:44351/signin-oidc
    &response_type=id_token
    &scope=openid profile
    &response_mode=form_post
    &nonce=636928196846064501.OGRlYjM0NjgtZDJlYi00M2UxLTk5YzQtM2MxM
    &state=CfDJ8EfHCTrLjBNKqHfPd-IQcycV6rNTyFU3zZeqHtwCOoO5tRFUx_5xLhFlvuFi_y9HbC_rhNEGL4qss5sG986p4zZCU
    &x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD1_4
    &x-client-ver=5.2.0.0
```

Startup class & OpenIdConnect Middleware

```
    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddAzureAdB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("Authentication:AzureAdB2C", options))
            .AddCookie(options => {
                options.LoginPath = "/Session/Unauthorized/";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Session/Forbidden/";
            });

OpeidConnect Middleware
public static class AzureAdB2CAuthenticationBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAdB2C(this AuthenticationBuilder builder)
            => builder.AddAzureAdB2C(_ =>
            {
            });
        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAdB2C(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AzureAdB2COptions> configureOptions)
        {
            builder.Services.Configure(configureOptions);
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup>();
            builder.AddOpenIdConnect();
            return builder;
        }
        public class OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup : IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
        {
            private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

            public OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup(IOptions<AzureAdB2COptions> b2cOptions, IMemoryCache cache)
            {
                _cache = cache;
                AzureAdB2COptions = b2cOptions.Value;

        }

            public AzureAdB2COptions AzureAdB2COptions { get; set; }

            public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
            {
                options.ClientId = AzureAdB2COptions.ClientId;
                options.Authority = AzureAdB2COptions.Authority;
                options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() { NameClaimType = "name" };

                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
                {
                    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                    OnRemoteFailure = OnRemoteFailure,
                    OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived
                };
            }

            public void Configure(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
            {
                Configure(Options.DefaultName, options);
            }

            public Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectContext context)
            {
                var defaultPolicy = AzureAdB2COptions.DefaultPolicy;
                if (context.Properties.Items.TryGetValue(AzureAdB2COptions.PolicyAuthenticationProperty, out var policy) &&
                    !policy.Equals(defaultPolicy))
                {
                    context.ProtocolMessage.Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile;
                    context.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
                    context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.ToLower().Replace(defaultPolicy.ToLower(), policy.ToLower());
                    context.Properties.Items.Remove(AzureAdB2COptions.PolicyAuthenticationProperty);
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AzureAdB2COptions.ApiUrl))
                {
                    context.ProtocolMessage.Scope += $" offline_access {AzureAdB2COptions.ApiScopes}";
                    context.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }

            public Task OnRemoteFailure(RemoteFailureContext context)
            {
                context.HandleResponse();
                // Handle the error code that Azure AD B2C throws when trying to reset a password from the login page 
                // because password reset is not supported by a "sign-up or sign-in policy"
                if (context.Failure is OpenIdConnectProtocolException && context.Failure.Message.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
                {
                    // If the user clicked the reset password link, redirect to the reset password route
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Session/ResetPassword");
                }
                else if (context.Failure is OpenIdConnectProtocolException && context.Failure.Message.Contains("access_denied"))
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("/");
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + context.Failure.Message);
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }

            public async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
            {
                // Use MSAL to swap the code for an access token
                // Extract the code from the response notification
                var code = context.ProtocolMessage.Code;

                string signedInUserID = context.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, context.HttpContext).GetMsalCacheInstance();
                ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientId, AzureAdB2COptions.Authority, AzureAdB2COptions.RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);
                try
                {
                    AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, AzureAdB2COptions.ApiScopes.Split(' '));


                    context.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //TODO: Handle
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you created B2C tenant? What problem you encountered , please share some more information

Comment: yes, i did. added more information in the description. thanks

Comment: Hi @jalil. You aren't including the `prompt=login` parameter in the authentication request are you?

Comment: hi @ChrisPadgett, i didn't use prompt=login. i update description with my login profile. Thanks

Comment: Hi @jalil. Are all of the different applications using the same host? Either **login.microsoftonline.com** or **your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com** (recommended)?

Comment: hi @ChrisPadgett, same host, same tanent

Comment: Hi @jalil, could you please include your OpenIdConnect middleware configuration?

Comment: hi @TiagoBrenck, i update description. hope it will to identify root cause. Thanks